# Convert HTML list in word to bulleted list

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I create a macro in VBA (Word) that will run through:

```
<ul><li>this is just a test</li><li>woop</li><li>test</li></ul>
```

and generate a

- this is just a test
- woop
- test

Using Word 2010.

Reason for this is the html comes in via mailmerge from a 3rd party system.

This HAS to be done through a macro for my endusers! :)

More Details:
I will have to create something as the following that searches for the Italic html tag and inserts Font.Italic instead.

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "[<][iI][>]*[<]/[iI][>]"
    .Replacement.Font.Italic = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

So my question is, how do I, like this, run through the document and finds the `<ul>` instance and loops through each of the `<li>` tags and inserts the text in the tag as a bulleted list...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to achieve what you want.

**LOGIC**

1. Create an IE instance
2. Set the `.InnerHTML` to your html string
3. Copy the contents from IE to word

In Short, let IE do the dirty work.

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim strHtml As String

    strHtml = "<ul><li>this is just a test</li><li>woop</li><li>test</li></ul>"

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Visible = True

    ie.Navigate "about:blank"

    ie.Document.body.InnerHTML = strHtml

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    ie.Document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"

    Selection.Paste
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: that could Work, but I would like a more clean approach, also for the endusers

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "Clean Approach"?

Comment: I don't want to open IE for doing this stuff, I wan't it all contained in the find so i replace everything in the <UL> tag with an iteration of each <LI> tag and use the vba WdListType.wdListBullet to insert each text contained in the <LI>